# an error in my MySQL script syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on a table before update, but I'm seeing an error after that :

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) ' at line 8

This is my script :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `accepterLivraion` BEFORE UPDATE ON `LigneInterventaire`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.etat = 'Accepté' THEN
        IF verifierLivraison(OLD.num) = FALSE THEN
            SIGNAL sqlstate '45001' set message_text = "La livraison n'a pas respectée les termes de la commande de sortie.";
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO Inventaire(`date`) VALUES (DATE(NOW());
            INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
            VALUES (NEW.codeArt, NEW.qte, LAST_INSERT_ID());
        END IF;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

where is the problem in my script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing bracket on this line:

```
INSERT INTO Inventaire(`date`) VALUES (DATE(NOW()));
```